# How solr+node.js+mongoDB works?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, solr

HI I am using a nodeJS application. I trying to use solr-client to serch.

I wanted know does I have to add data to solr those are available in mongoDB or solr can search from there.

And I am running the application in port number 4000, do I have to run another server on port number 8983 to solr-client or solr itself can take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

First, populate your mongoDB collection. Then, create a json file with the content of your collection (mongoexport command). Finally, update your Solr collection with your json file.